# How to access a Image file in a Eclipse Project Folder

Tags: java, eclipse, image, directory

I have a single image file in a folder in my Eclipse project that stores a image file (logo.jpg). However I don't know how to access it in my main program.

I had tried the following

```
private static URL logoPath

public class MainApplication
{
     public void createGui()
     {
          logoPath.getClass().getResource("/Resources/images/logo.jpg");
          ////
     }
     /////
}
```

Problem is I keep getting a null pointer exception so obviously that path is done wrong or else the logoPath.getClass() is tripping it up.

Any ideas?

Comment: No takers? I want to store an image to use as a logo when im distributing the JAR file so i need to make sure im referencing the appropriate location each time rather then a set location on my pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place your resources in a java source directory for them to be visible. You have two options:

1. Move your "resources" folder under your existing "src" folder.
2. Create a new source folder just for resources. You can do that in Java Build Path page of project properties.

Several things to watch out for...

1. Pay attention to your capitalization. Java resource lookup is case sensitive.
2. The path that you would use will be relative to the source folder (not project root). For instance, if you make your resources folder a source folder, your path will need to be "images/...". If you want to preserve resources folder in the lookup path, you will need to create an extra folder level in your project to serve as the source root for resources.
3. I am not certain whether it is an actual problem, but resources paths should not start with a leading slash. They aren't really paths in a traditional sense. Think of them as package-qualified class names, but with '/' instead of '.' as the separator.

Comment: Okay what exactly is the difference between a "folder" and a "source folder"? Secondly are you saying that the "resources" folder should be within the src folder? Thirdly putting all that together i should be look for something like this `logoPath.getClass().getResource("resources/logo.jpg");`

Comment: To be precise, a Java Source Folder (as specified in Java Build Path panel of project properties) controls the extent where Eclipse Java support looks for .java source file and their associated resources. Everything else in the project is invisible. If you put "resources/logo.jpg" in your existing "src" folder, then getResource("resources/logo.jpg") is indeed the correct invocation.

Comment: So I finally got this working. It ended up working with this `URL logoPath = new MainApplication().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("logo.jpg");` though my problem now is that this works fine on my machine but not on different machines

Answer (score 6):

U can use this way
**I have following package structure**

- src/test (package test contain Java files)
- src/images (folder images contain images)

I am going to get image from 
**src/images/login.png** at **src/test/*.java**

`JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/login.png")));`

Comment: I am not sure this is relevant to the question - someone?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing that the same way

```
 String filename = "logo.jpg";

 Main.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename);
```

And the file structure looks like this

/src/main/java/com/hauke/Main.java

/resource/logo.jpg

My problem was before that I named the direcotry "resources" and it should be "resource"