# Unable to find image file from a class: java

Tags: java

I am trying to load an image file from java but unable to do it.
Java Code:

```
String image="com/image.png";
System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource("Test.class"));
System.out.println(new File(image).exists());
```

Output is:

```
/home/user/build/classes/com/ui/Test.class
false
```

package structure is

```
src    
  com/image.png    
  com/ui/Test.java
```

If I use absolute path, I am able to find the file.

Any idea why I am unable to get the file using above code?

Comment: Look here: [Look at this][1]
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787368/how-to-access-a-image-file-in-a-eclipse-project-folder I think this works for you.

Comment: I tried it that way. It did not work. Can it be because build path is different? I have given build path as: /home/user/build/classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using two different mechanisms to load your resources in this example.  The `Test.class` resource is loaded from the classpath, but you're loading your image file from the filesystem. If you change your code to use the `getResource` method on the loading class or the current Thread's `ClassLoader`, you should be able to load your image. Otherwise you'll need to specify the correct filesystem path to the image you're trying to load.

You can get the Thread's `ClassLoader` from the `Thread.getContextClassLoader()`.

If you still can't load the image, you may need a leading `/` on your path.  I don't directly load resources from the classpath that often, and I forget whether this is needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the full path of the image, or you can try to put it under WebContent and make its path "WebContent/com/image.png".

Comment: What WebContent? There's no indication that this is a webapp.

Comment: You may try printing your current working directory and then see what is the path of the image.png. com/image.png should work if your current working directory is src.

Comment: This is not a webcontent. Also, this will be bundled as a jar at a later point of time.